# Kotlin coroutine await on UI thread

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

At the moment in my codebase, using `Kotlin`, I have an extension function that works in the following manner.

```
async {
    executeSomeCodeToGetResult()
}.awaitOnUiThread { result ->
    useResultOnUiThread(result)
}
```

The `async` function loads a runnable onto an `ExecutorService` which returns a `Future<T>` result. `awaitOnUiThread` is an extension function on the `Future<T>` object that sends `T` as an argument to the input function.

I was wondering if there is a way using `Kotlin` `coroutines` to achieve a similar result?

I did implement something like this but I didn't get very good performance results. Maybe I'm doing something wrong running the `await()` function on the `GlobalScope`?

```
private const val threadPoolSize = 4

@ObsoleteCoroutinesApi
val scope = CoroutineScope(newFixedThreadPoolContext(threadPoolSize, "async-runner"))

@ObsoleteCoroutinesApi
fun <T> async(function: () -> T): Deferred<T> {
    return scope.async { function() }
}

fun <T> Deferred<T>.awaitOnUiThread(function: (T) -> Unit) {
    val deferred = this
    GlobalScope.launch {
        val result: T = deferred.await()
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
            function(result)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With coroutines you shouldn't need any of `async` and `awaitOnGuiThread`. You should use the following idiom:

```
launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
    val result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        executeSomeCodeToGetResult()
    }
    ... just keep using the result
}
```

At least this is a rough first approximation. Kotlin's coroutine system wants you to also explicitly deal with failures and cancellation. This topic goes by the name of [structured concurrency](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/coroutines-on-android-part-ii-getting-started-3bff117176dd). The best place to start is the `ViewModel` because it has [built-in support](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/easy-coroutines-in-android-viewmodelscope-25bffb605471) for structured concurrency.

Comment: actually he can use `async` but that is not the right `async` he is using. notice that the `async` returns a `Deferred<T>` while the `launch` brings back a `JOB`

Comment: This seems like a good solution, I guess I'm trying to be too generic. I wanted to create a function that you could call anywhere within your kotlin, android, codebase that will run whatever operation on the background thread and propagate the result to the UI thread without writing too much code.

Comment: I was actually using something like the code specified in the above answer, it just broke the flow of the function defined in the question. I also saw that `Dispatchers.IO` seems to run on shared background threads when used with `withContext`.

Comment: Yes, you should use Dispatchers.IO to execute a blocking operation and Dispatchers.Default for a CPU-heavy computation. These transfer your coroutine to a background thread. You can keep going on Dispatchers.Main for suspending operations like async IO or awaiting an event.